# Обработка нажатия кнопки

Tags: c#

Как для `button1.click` применить цикл `if`, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выполнялся код, например: если нажата кнопка, то к 'а' присвоить значение находящееся в `textBox1`. В какой форме мне написать его?

Comment: Цикл ``if`` О_о

Comment: Ну я, наверное, не так выразился, хочу сделать вот так:

я напишу код для Delphi, может так будет понятнее:

    if button1.click then a:=b+c;

Теперь надо этот код для с# написать.

Comment: Вы получите более точный ответ на свой вопрос, если более грамотно его сформулируете. if - это не цикл, и ни циклы, ни условия не связаны с обработчиками нажатия кнопки. Вы могли бы написать что-то вроде: "как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки выполнялся определённый код?" Вы это хотели спросить?

Comment: да! а точнее если нажата кнопка, то чтобы выполнялся определенный код, можете помочь?

Answer (score 2):

Двойное нажатие на кнопку создаст для вас автоматически обработчик, в котором вы добавите нужное вам поведение. Для вашего примера будет нечто следующее:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = textBoxName.Text;
}
```

Не совсем понятно зачем вы в вопрос добавили ключевое слово *if* да еще и называли его циклом. Могу только предположить, что вы хотите в зависимости от нажатой кнопки сделать некое поведение, но при этом в одном разработчике. Для подобной реализации вам нужно выделить все нужные кнопки и опять таки создать автоматически один обработчик для них всех. Для определения какова из кнопок была нажата вам нужно параметр события *sender* преобразовать к типу *кнопка* и "смотреть" по его свойствам.

```
var btn = sender as Button;
...
```